# Android - Passing complex interface to JobScheduler

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I want to run a job using JobScheduler, and within that job I need to execute a method on a class which is an implementation of a specific interface, so it isn't a POJO or something like that which can easily be passed as a JSON string.

What I currently thought was to serialize that class to a file and then retrieve it later from within the JobService.

Is there any better way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the build-in method `setClipData(ClipData, int)` - [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder#setClipData(android.content.ClipData,%20int)), where you could apply deserialization of that object in the moment, when the Job will be triggered.